# Cast to ObjectId failed for value at path for model error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

**This is my Profile Schema:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        // Special field type because
        // it will be associated to different user
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user',
    },
    company: {
        type: String,
    },
    website: {
        type: String,
    },
    location: {
        type: String,
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    skills: {
        type: [String],
        required: true,
    },
    bio: {
        type: String,
    },
    githubusername: {
        type: String,
    },
    experience: [
        {
            title: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            company: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            location: {
                type: String,
            },
            from: {
                type: Date,
                required: true,
            },
            to: {
                type: Date,
            },
            current: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false,
            },
            description: {
                type: String,
            },
        },
    ],
    education: [
        {
            school: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            degree: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            fieldofstudy: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            from: {
                type: Date,
                required: true,
            },
            to: {
                type: Date,
            },
            current: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false,
            },
            description: {
                type: String,
            },
        },
    ],
    social: {
        youtube: {
            type: String,
        },
        twitter: {
            type: String,
        },
        facebook: {
            type: String,
        },
        linkedin: {
            type: String,
        },
        instagram: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model('profile', ProfileSchema);
```

This is my view api. It doesn't work. it only return Cast to ObjectId failed for value `{ 'experience._id': '5edcb6933c0bb75b3c90a263' }` at path `_id` for model `profile`

```
router.get('/experience/viewing/:viewexp_id', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const exp = await Profile.findById({
            'experience._id': req.params.viewexp_id,
        });

        if (!exp) {
            return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Experience not found' });
        }

        res.json(exp);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send(err.message);
    }
});
```

How can I fix this? I tried looking at the stackoverflow of the same errors. still it doesn't seem to work.

and this is what I am trying to hit

[image: Mongodb experience Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have to convert your string `_id` to `mongoose object id` using this function `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` and my suggestion is to use `findOne` function instead of `findById`,

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

router.get('/experience/viewing/:viewexp_id', auth, async (req, res) => {
    
    try {

        let id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.viewexp_id);
        
        const exp = await Profile.findOne(
            { "experience._id": req.params.viewexp_id }, 
            // This will show your sub record only and exclude parent _id
            { "experience.$": 1, "_id": 0 }
        );

        if (!exp) {
            return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Experience not found' });
        }

        res.json(exp);

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send(err.message);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used the id that you declared from { "experience._id": req.params.viewexp_id } to { "experience._id": id } since you declared it.

Comment: {
    "_id": "5ed209b58c14a956648db0b4",
    "experience": [
        {
            "current": true,
            "_id": "5edcb6933c0bb75b3c90a263",
            "title": "JUNE 8 2020",
            "company": "Grizzly Bear",
            "location": "Quezon City",
            "from": "2012-01-25T16:00:00.000Z",
            "description": "Master Grizzly Bear"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: and lastly is it normal that i returns the Id of that user? why is  it included? not just the experience one data?

Comment: I don't know but you can exclude main `_id` from this result do this inside your projection `{ "experience.$": 1. "_id": 0 }` and also edited in answer look in to it, I will look in to your query, when i get chance today about how to get direct record. and I have upvoted your questions :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

router.get('/experience/viewing/:viewexp_id', auth, async (req, res) => {
try {
    const exp = await Profile.findOne({
        'experience._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.viewexp_id),
    });

    if (!exp) {
        return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Experience not found' });
    }

    res.json(exp);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
}
});
```

You are saving object id . but your param id is string. convert it in ObjectId. Please check my solution.

Comment: This returns all of the Profile information. It doesn't return the one experience of that User

Answer (score 0):

```js
router.post(
  "/",
  [
    auth,
    [
      check("status", "status is required").not().isEmpty(),
      check("skills", "skills is required").not().isEmpty(),
    ],
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const {
      company,
      website,
      location,
      bio,
      status,
      githubuername,
      skills,
      youtube,
      facebook,
      twitter,
      instagram,
      linkedin,
    } = req.body;

    const profileFileds = {};
    profileFileds.user = req.user.id;
    if (company) profileFileds.company = company;
    if (website) profileFileds.website = website;
    if (location) profileFileds.location = location;
    if (bio) profileFileds.bio = bio;
    if (status) profileFileds.status = status;
    if (githubuername) profileFileds.githubuername = githubuername;
    if (skills) {
      profileFileds.skills = skills.split(",").map((skill) => skill.trim());
    }

    //Build profile object
    profileFileds.social = {};

    if (youtube) profileFileds.social.youtube = youtube;
    if (twitter) profileFileds.social.twitter = twitter;
    if (facebook) profileFileds.social.facebook = facebook;
    if (linkedin) profileFileds.social.linkedin = linkedin;
    if (instagram) profileFileds.social.instagram = instagram;

    try {
      let profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });

      if (profile) {
        //update
        profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
          { user: req.user.id },
          { $set: profileFileds },
          { new: true }
        );
        return res.json(profile);
      }

      //Create profile
      profile = new Profile(profileFileds);
      await profile.save();
      res.json(profile);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send("server Error");
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.